# Update failed, how to restart it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

As you can see in the screenshot below, the update has failed. Windows 10 update is now not downloading. How can I restart this failed update?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the update "Failed" then it should still be available in Windows Update for you to download/install again.

Head back to the WU UI and look for it.

*Note:* you may have to reboot and/or rescan for updates to have it (re)appear after the failure.